# Using sparklyr tbl to environment and assigning data accordingly?

Tags: r, sparklyr

I am new to `spark` Let's suppose I have  "connections" in a database as:

```
a <- data.frame(a = c(1:3), b = sample(letters, 3), c = rep(1))
b <- data.frame(as = c(1:3), b1 = sample(letters, 3), c2 = rep(2), d = c("KISS", "Scorpion", "Poison"))
c <- data.frame(qn = c(10:20), rj = sample(LETTERS, 11))
```

That I can access using the following code:

```
conf <- spark_config()
conf$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "16G"
conf$`spark.memory.fraction` <- 0.8
conf$`spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` <- "2g"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "", spark_home = "", config = conf, version = "2.3.1")
```

I can move these to my environment by using

```
tbs <- src_tbls(sc)

data <- lapply(tbs, function(x) tbl(sc, x))
```

In my environment, I would like to have 3 separate data.frames or tibbles as 'a' 'b' and 'c'. Anyone have any idea of how I can achieve this? I have over 200 datasets I need to do this to which is why I am using `lapply`.

I did try to no avail:

```
lapply(tbs, function(x) assign(x, tbl(sc,x)))
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you call a data set a "connection"? What are you really try to achieve in words?

Comment: It's a bit complicated (for me at least). I am new to Spark in general, but there is a tab in my Rstudio Rserver interface that sales "Connections" (next to Environment and History, which are standard in Rstudio). I am trying to move many of the datasets present in the "Connections" tab to the Global Environment.

Comment: Do you want to move the tables from Spark to R or vice versa?

Comment: I need to move the datasets from Spark to Rserver

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch one table ("a", say) like this:

```
library(DBI)
a <- dbGetQuery(sc, paste("SELECT * FROM a"))
```

Now, since you have a lot of tables in your Spark environment, you can do the same in an `lapply`, moving all tables into a list of `data.frame`s.

```
table_names <- src_tbls(sc)
data_list <- lapply(table_names,
             function(x) dbGetQuery(sc, paste("SELECT * FROM", x)))
names(data_list) <- table_names
```

If you really, really, really want to take the list elements out of the list, you would write `attach(data_list)`. It is considered as very bad programming and will complicate further steps considerably.